# Upload Content Version using REST Api

Tags: rest-api, rest, contentversion

I am referring to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm documentation for Content Version and getting this error " You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request" . Can anyone help

Comment: can you please check the following disucssion :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273942/improperly-formatted-request-error-after-switching-from-commons-httpclient-to

Comment: Have you managed to upload a ContentVerison? I'm trying to upload Files and link them to Cases via the REST API but haven't figured out how yet. Have you followed this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion?

Answer (score 0):

See [Status Codes and Error Responses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm) in the same document you've referenced.

The error means you've requested a resource that doesn’t exist, for example, if you try to create a record using a misspelled object name. Check your code for errors of that nature.